# Microsoft Fabric PowerBI workspace migration

Tags: azure, microsoft-fabric

I have ( Environment, Lakehouse, DataPipeline, Warehouse, Ml model, Spark Job Definition ) in my microsoft fabric powerbi workspace. Now i want to migrate it to another account can someone tell me how can i achieve it? Can i create Infrastructure as Code for them or what please someone guide me

I have tried to download files for these or any other resource but was not able to find for these resources please guide me